# Chrome desktop notifications use notify-osd?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, notify-osd

Is there a way to make Chrome/Chromium's notifications use notify-osd instead of the ugly boxes it uses by default?

Comment: Probably not helpful, but... use Firefox instead of Chrome and you can enjoy native system notifications with [GNotifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnotifier/).

Comment: Pssst @ByteCommander FF said check is in the mail.

Comment: Firefox is still free as in free beer, I won't get anything for recommending it except the good feeling that one or two people might have switched to a better browser... (IMNSHO) @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @ByteCommander I shameless promote Linux all the time even going so far as wearing a baseball cap with a Penguin. You are doing a great job and I was just teasing you. You had me at free beer....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yeah: [Chromify-OSD](https://launchpad.net/chromify-osd).

[image]

This can be installed from the [Google Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmgdlkljbfeeinemfljcbmnkmbeligmn).

To install it, just go to the webstore and click the "Add to Chrome" button - it'll do the rest.

To use it, you'll *probably* need to restart Chrome, at that point it should be working.

All bugs should be reported to the [launchpad.net project page](https://launchpad.net/chromify-osd) - for more on reporting bugs, take a look at this question: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as fluteflute said, any help in installing it?

Comment: You just have to go to the site mentioned and click install.

Comment: Hm, it does not appear to work.  I've installed it, restarted Chromium for good measure, and went to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/ to test.  I get ugly white boxes in the lower-right screen corner instead of pretty black OSD bubbles in the upper-right corner.

Comment: Oh, silly me TL;DRed on the description in the web store.  "This is a first release which does not support HTML5 notifications (but will in next release, view LaunchPad project page)".  What *other* Chromium notifications are there?

Comment: There is a new fork which is recently updated: [LinuxNativeNotification](https://github.com/tualatrix/LinuxNativeNotification) featured on [OMGubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/how-to-get-chrome-to-use-ubuntu-notifications)

Answer (score 4):

Since NPAPI is gone, pretty much every solution is dead. It looks like there's currently only one solution, and it isn't great.

[Libnotify Notifications in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/libnotify-notifications-i/epckjefillidgmfmclhcbaembhpdeijg)

It is rated very low, but that's most likely because it is still incomplete. It also requires a piece of software to run on the machine itself, so it's not the most easy installation.

However, if you can run scripts and are willing to take security risks, this may work great for you, as long as you don't expect it to work with everything (the author says Gmail is currently in the works).

Sadly, it seems that Google's decision to kill NPAPI in Chromium has also killed this convenience measure.

I will continue to research, but at the moment, this is the only solution I can find that isn't over a year old.

Comment: its a bit buggy but it does work

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed it in Chrome, Click on the Wrench Icon, then select the Prefences Menu, then Extensions and you should see:

[image: The Chromify-OSD extension Icon]

The Chromify-OSD extension Icon and that it is enabled. The extension is now installed and enabled.

The only other requirement to make this work is that you have the notify-osd packages installed in your system or this will not do anything at all.

HTH. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04 and Chrome 30, It is not working :-(

Comment: this only works on old insecure chromes as noted in other answers

Comment: @Amias this answer was written in 2011. It was more valid at the time.