# Chromify OSD isn't working in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, chromium, notify-osd

Based on these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25811/chrome-desktop-notifications-use-notify-osd), I have installed the Google Chrome / Chromium extension Chromify-OSD. But I can't see it working properly.

Look at this image to know what I mean.

[image]

How to make these notifications look like notify OSD?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Apparently, in the latest stable version of Chrome, Chromify-OSD is broken. A fix will be released shortly and your version will automagically be upgraded when it's available. Follow [Chromify-OSD.com](http://chromify-osd.com) for details

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is really a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/chromify-osd/+bug/884561). Anyway, here is a temporary fix.

For amd64:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.1
```

For i386:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the description of add-on in the web store says "This is a first release which does not support HTML5 notifications (but will in next release, view LaunchPad project page)". And I guess this is HTML5 notification which is currently unsupported. Hence its being displayed normally instead of native notifications